# Alternatives for java.util.Date

Tags: java, java.util.date

Currently I am using the deprecated `set` Methods of `java.util.Date`. As I want to migrate away from it, what are the alternatives and what advantages do they have?

I need to have a `Date` that is set to today, midnight for a `HQL` query that selects everything that happened today.

Currently I use:

```
Date startingDate = new Date();
startingDate.setHours(0);
startingDate.setMinutes(0);
startingDate.setSeconds(0);
```

Comment: Please read javadoc... its clearly mentioned that `Calendar.set` methods are replacements

Comment: If you describe more abstract what you want to do, it would be possible to give you more direct advice.

Comment: I am using these date variable in Hibernate query to search for records which are created on the same day starting from 12:00 AM.

Comment: Can you use the databases date functions for that (and if yes, what database do you use?)

Comment: Currently i am restricted to only Java level changes. I use Postgresql DB.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### NOTE

This answer is most likely no longer accurate for Java 8 and beyond, because there is a [better date/calendar API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) now.

---

The standard alternate is using the `Calendar` Object.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // that is NOW for the timezone configured on the computer.
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

`Calendar` has the advantage to come without additional libraries and is widely understood. It is also the documented alternative from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#setMinutes%28int%29) of `Date`

The documentation of `Calendar` can be found here: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)

`Calendar` has one dangerous point (for the unwary) and that is the `after` / `before` methods. They take an `Object` but will only handle `Calendar` Objects correctly. Be sure to read the Javadoc for these methods closely before using them.

You can transform `Calendar` Objects in quite some way like:

- add a day (`cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);`)
- "scroll" through the week (`cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);`)
- etc

Have a read of the class description in the Javadoc to get the full picture.

Comment: And the `#set` method therein: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#set(int, int, int, int, int, int)

Answer (score 3):

The best alternative is to use the [Joda Time API](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
Date date = new DateMidnight().toDate();     // today at 00:00
```

To avoid the to-be deprecated `DateMidnight`:

```
Date date = new DateTime().withMillisOfDay(0).toDate();
```

Comment: could you add code to show how to do what the OP said with Joda?

Comment: DateMidnight()  is deprecated in the latest joda build

Comment: That's right. See my edit :)

Comment: A better way to get first moment of day is to call this method in Joda-Time 2.3:  `DateTime.now().withTimeAtStartOfDay()`. Even better is to specify the desired time zone rather than rely on implicit default: `DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" ) ).withTimeAtStartOfDay()`.

Answer (score 2):

Date does not handle internationalization properly, that's why it was deprecated.

> Prior to JDK 1.1, the class Date had two additional functions. It
>   allowed the interpretation of dates as year, month, day, hour, minute,
>   and second values. It also allowed the formatting and parsing of date
>   strings. Unfortunately, the API for these functions was not amenable
>   to internationalization. As of JDK 1.1, the Calendar class should be
>   used to convert between dates and time fields and the DateFormat class
>   should be used to format and parse date strings. The corresponding
>   methods in Date are deprecated.

The simplest alternative is to use [`java.util.Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) instead:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // get a calendar instance (current)
```

and the call
calendar.set(...) methods.

Answer (score -1):

You may use joda dates library , you will get lots of flexibility with that. Otherwise you can use java.util.Calendar for creating custom date.

Answer (score -2):

1、The alternate is using the `java.util.Calendar` Object;

2、Detailed usage, please refer to the link below;

http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/other/10time/30calendar.html